# flutter: EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY: A RenderFlex overflowed by n pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When deploying the onscreen keyboard on android, flutter throws an exception and renders a yellow and black striped pattern. The exception message explains why and how to avoid this but I fail to understand why is this an error condition in the first place. Can I just ignore it and if not how to properly handle it.

[image: bottom overflowed by 128 pixels]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A quick solution would be to block the widgets inside the `Scaffold` to resize themselves when the keyboard opens. We can do this using the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property on the Scaffold widget.

```
     Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: .....,
      ),
```

OR

2. Another solution is to wrap the `Column` widget into a `scrollable` widget. A built-in widget provided by Flutter which works well is the `SingleChildScrollView`. This is the best solution to avoid the `Bottom overflowed` error when the keyboard opens.

Comment: Thanks this does not answer my question: why is it an error condition. Actually it's supposed to be a login screen so a scroll view won't work. I tried the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to false but the keyboard now hides the second TextField

Comment: Read the article I provided @Imaxd, https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660

Comment: SingleChildScrollView works great. Thank you but I had to make it wrap a Column to work, Like the article describes.

Comment: Glad to hear!. Happy Fluttering :)